# Appending to AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor fails

Tags: swift, avfoundation, core-video, core-media

I want to output a video file from the depth camera. Displaying the data works, but cannot append the pixelBuffer to the AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor. Unfortunately, there is no more info then a negative boolean.

In this function we setup the writer

```
func createWriter() {
        do {
            assetWriter = try AVAssetWriter(outputURL: movieURL() as URL, fileType: AVFileType.mov)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        let outputSettings = [
            AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecType.h264,
            AVVideoWidthKey : Int(currentVideoDimensions!.width),
            AVVideoHeightKey : Int(currentVideoDimensions!.height)
            ] as [String : Any]

        let assetWriterVideoInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaType.video, outputSettings: outputSettings)
        assetWriterVideoInput.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(.pi / 2.0))
        assetWriterVideoInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true

        let sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary = [
            String(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey) : Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA),
            String(kCVPixelBufferWidthKey) : Int(currentVideoDimensions!.width),
            String(kCVPixelBufferHeightKey) : Int(currentVideoDimensions!.height),
            String(kCVPixelFormatOpenGLESCompatibility) : kCFBooleanTrue!
            ] as [String : Any]

        assetWriterPixelBufferInput = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(assetWriterInput: assetWriterVideoInput, sourcePixelBufferAttributes: sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary)

        if assetWriter!.canAdd(assetWriterVideoInput) {
            assetWriter!.add(assetWriterVideoInput)
        } else {
            print("no way\(assetWriterVideoInput)")
        }
    }
```

which is used later to append the pixelbuffers after a frame is recorded

```
public func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        autoreleasepool {

            connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.landscapeLeft;

            let pixelBuffer : CVPixelBuffer? = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
            let cameraImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer!)

            let previewImage: CIImage
            previewImage = depthMap ?? cameraImage

            let displayImage = UIImage(ciImage: previewImage)

            let formatDescription = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(sampleBuffer)!
            self.currentVideoDimensions = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(formatDescription)
            self.currentSampleTime = CMSampleBufferGetOutputPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)

            if self.isWriting {
                if self.assetWriterPixelBufferInput?.assetWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData == true {let success = self.assetWriterPixelBufferInput?.append(pixelBuffer!, withPresentationTime: self.currentSampleTime!)

                    if success == false {
                        print("Pixel Buffer failed")
                    }
                }
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                self?.imageView.image = displayImage
            }
        }
    }
```

We checked Image and Buffer sizes and they were the same, appending still doesn't work and there is no proper error message.